# Cannot find nifi processor called PutHive3QL

Tags: apache-nifi

Using Nifi `1.11.3`, I am not able to find the processor called [`PutHive3QL`](https://www.mvndoc.com/c/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hive3-processors/org/apache/nifi/processors/hive/PutHive3QL.html).

This processor does not show up in the "Add processor" panel. I only have [`PutHiveQL`](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hive-nar/1.11.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveQL/index.html).

How can I add or where can I find this processor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hive 3 components are not included with the NiFi distribution due to size limitations, but they are built and published as part of the release process. For version 1.11.3, you can find the NAR [here](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/nifi/nifi-hive3-nar/1.11.3/).

Comment: How many such processors are not included in the main distribution? Can we find that list somewhere?